# Module does not exist in module map

Tags: typescript, react-native

My react native project is written using typescript with this structure:

```
|--Src
|   |--App.tsx
|   |--Models
|       |--User.ts
|--index.ios.js
|--index.android.js
```

Where **App.tsx** is like:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text} from 'react-native'
import * as M from 'models'

interface Props {}
interface State {}

export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    render()
    {

        let user = new M.User();

        return(
            <Text> Test </Text>
        )
    }
}
```

and **User.ts** is

```
declare module "models" {

    class User {

        name : string;
    }
}
```

Here is the **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

The problem is when run project I encounter this error:

> The module doesn't exist in module map

It seems it cannot locate the module *models*. How can I fix it?

Here is the screen shot of error:

[image]

Comment: @Saravana I think "module map" refers to a map of module names and their location or something that typescript is responsible to create.

Comment: As far as I know, it is the React Native packager which resolves imports. When you transpile the files, the transformer feeds it on a file-by-file basis. I'm not sure how the packager will be able to resolve TypeScript modules.

Comment: @cbrevik is right in that the packager is unable to resolve TypeScript modules. You may want to take a look at Tom Duncalf's post about this - a lot of great info. http://blog.tomduncalf.com/posts/setting-up-typescript-and-react/